# Spotting difference in specific fields

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, A and B, with same variables but potentially different observations:

A

```
Name surname time
1427  4624   06-12-2020
1427  5272   07-13-2021
2642  5281   03-12-2022
…
```

B

```
Name surname time
1427 4624    06-12-2021
1427 5273    07-13-2021
2642 5281    03-12-2022
…
```

I would like to check the differences, if any, whether a name has different surname and/or time across the two tables.
I have tried using a left join

```
Select distinct a.name, a.surname as surname_a, b.surname as surname_b
From a
Left join b
On a.name=b.name
Where surname_a<>surname_b
And a.time<>b.time
```

The output should be a list of all the combinations of name/surname whether a difference in surname/time is found.
The problem with the query above is that, when I consider the full dataset, returns the observations in different rows, for example:

Output

```
Name surname_a surname_b
1427  4624      5273
1427  5273      4624
```

…

And this is wrong.
My expected output would be

```
Name surname 

1427 4624      (Because of date)
1427 5272      (Because missing in table b)
1427 5273      (Because missing in table A)
```

As so often, the main task is to get it straight what the query shall do exactly. Let's look at a simple example:

### More sample data

**Table A**

| Name | surname | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1427 | 1000 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1427 | 1000 | 2020-02-02 |
| 1427 | 2000 | 2020-02-02 |
| 1427 | 3000 | 2020-03-03 |
| 2257 | 4000 | 2020-04-04 |

**Table B**

| Name | surname | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1427 | 1000 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1427 | 1000 | 2020-04-04 |
| 1427 | 2000 | 2020-02-02 |
| 2231 | 2000 | 2020-04-04 |
| 2257 | 4000 | 2020-04-04 |

**Expected Result**

| Name | surname | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1427 | 1000 | 2020-02-02 |
| 1427 | 1000 | 2020-04-04 |
| 1427 | 2000 | 2020-04-04 |
| 2231 | 2000 | 2020-04-04 |
| 1427 | 3000 | 2020-03-03 |

Explanation: the fields in the expected results are selected based on differences in time across the two tables or because the value is missing in one of the two tables.

Comment: Sample data us great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Note that your WHERE clause conditions make the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. Move them to the ON clause if you want true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Can there be more than one row per name and surname in the tables? Can there be more than one row per name and date in the tables?

Comment: I have added a kind of form for clarification to your request. This is sample data with multiple rows for the same surname and multiple rows for the same date. Please fill in the table for the expected result and add an explanation what rules lead to this result.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. So you seem to want all name/surname pairs where exists a row in one of the tables that doesn't have an exact match in the other table. The time column is not needed in the results, I guess? Because they seem random and I would have to ask why it is 2020-02-02 for 1427|1000 and not 2020-04-04 (or any other date if there were even more entries with distinct dates for 1427|1000 in the tables.) So is my assumption correct? Do you want those name/surname pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all rows for which not exists a matching row in the other table. For this, full outer join the tables and only keep outer joined result rows.

```
Select 
  coalesce(a.name, b.name) as name,
  coalesce(a.surname, b.surname) as surname,
  coalesce(a.time, b.time) as time
from a
full outer join b  on b.name    = a.name
                  and b.surname = a.surname
                  and b.time    = a.time
where a.name is null or b.name is null;
```

Or select all rows from A that don't have a B match plus all rows from B that don't have an A match, glueing the two results tgether with `UNION ALL`.

```
select * from a where (name, surname, time) not in (select name, surname, time from b)
union all
select * from b where (name, surname, time) not in (select name, surname, time from a);
```

Comment: Thanks, Thorsten! Just a quick one: would this return also cases where surname is distinct across the two tables, or only if it misses in one of the two?

Comment: We don't look at surnames. We look at complete rows. Every row that is in one table, but not in the other is in the result. Every row that is in both tables, is not in the result.